# Call a method of another exe file which uses Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#

I have an C# console application, say `Project1`. A method uses settings as the following.

```
void Method1 () {
    var x = Properties.Settings.Default.XXXX;
}
```

The users can change the value in the `Project1.exe.config` and the method got the changed values.

Now I need to create a new console project, say `Project2`, in the same solution and the new project calls the method `Project1.Method1()` after adding reference. However, it always got the default value. I tried to

1. Add settings `XXXX` in `Project2` and changed the value in `Project2.exe.config`.

Project2.exe.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Project2.Properties.Setting>
    <settings name="XXXX" serializeAs="String">
      <value>....</value>
```

2. Copy `Project1.exe.config` to the bin\debug folder of `Project2` and change the settings in copied `Project1.exe.config`.

Neither one works. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the setting to `Project2`, just copy the config line from `Project1.exe.config` to `Project2.exe.config`.  Config files are for the running application, so the app needs all of the necessary config settings from dependent libraries (including other executables).

Comment: I did. But it doesn't get the changed value in `Project1.exe.config`.

Comment: `Project2.exe` won't read from `project1.exe.config`. You need to copy the config setting from `project1.exe.config`to `project1.exe.config` and change it _there_.

Comment: Both my `Project1.exe.config` and `Project2.exe.config` contain the code `      <setting name="XXXX" serializeAs="String">
        <value>....</value>
      </setting>`

Comment: But did you _add_ a setting within `Project2` with the same name? That's what I thought you meant by "Add settings `XXXX `in `Project2`.

Comment: Yes, they are both `XXXX`.

Comment: Remove the setting from `Project2`. The method is using the setting from `Project1` but it will read it from `Project2.exe.config`.

Comment: Removing settings and copy the lines from `Project1.exe.config` will get exception of Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Project2.Program' threw an
exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System
.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings. (D:\...

Comment: Hmm.  That's how you do it when you use a setting from a class library-  don't see why it would be different for an executable but I haven't tried that to be honest.